# Sending a set of generators in ring theory

Tags: ring-theory

(As suggested by Qiaochu, there were some ambiguity in this problem, thus I have adjusted accordingly.)

Suppose $R$ is a commutative unital ring and $\{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$ and $\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$ are two sets.

Then if I am looking at $A:=R[x_1,\cdots, x_n]$ and $B:=R[y_1,\cdots,y_n]$ (Basically two polynomials rings generated by two different sets) and consider the ring homomorphism that is $\phi:A\to B$ such that it is induced by $\phi(x_i)=y_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n.$ Is it necessary that $\phi(A)=B$? Or do we need to have $\phi$ itself being injective?

I am not sure if I explained my question clearly, let me know if there is anything I need to add. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: $\phi$ is injective and in fact bijective, assuming $A$ and $B$ are supposed to be polynomial rings here (there's a mild ambiguity in what you mean if $R$ is noncommutative but this is true with either interpretation).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you so much for your reply! However, could you please elaborate why $\phi$ must be surjective given that it is injective? (I tried to do it but at the end I did not use injectivity at all and so I assume my way must be false!) Thank you so much again!

Comment: $\phi$ is just bijective by definition; its inverse sends each $y_i$ to $x_i$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry I misread your first comment. I have understood now, thanks!